# Unicorn not starting when using mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn, mina

When I run mina unicorn:start, I get an error: /home/deployer/xxx-api/releases/7 not found . I am certain that directory exists on the server. Can you kindly take a look to know if it is a problem with mina or mina-unicorn.

> RAILS_ENV=production mina unicorn:start --verbose

```
Loading environment
$ source ~/.bashrc


Loading rbenv
$ export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"
$ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
$ eval "$(rbenv init -)"

-----> Starting Unicorn...
/home/deployer/xxx-api/releases/7 not found
Connection to 104.131.92.185 closed.

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 2560
```

Answer (score 0):

**BAD**:

I know, that it is actually hack, but I used this task called start_unicorn

```ruby
task :start_unicorn => :environment do
  queue "cd #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}; RAILS_EVN=#{rails_env} bundle exec unicorn -c #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"
end
```

then

```bash
mina start_unicorn
```

**GOOD**:

add path to gemfile in your deploy.rb file, in my case it will be:

```ruby
set :bundle_gemfile,"#{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/Gemfile"
```

The same solution you can find at the following issue:
https://github.com/openteam/mina-unicorn/issues/8